# Selecting text using Javascript in bootstrap modal dialog is not working in IE11. But, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a task where text in a div has been to selected on button click event. The select is not working if the div is in bootstrap modal dialog.

The following code works in chrome but not in IE11.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b8thg39u/5/

Code:

```
$('#BtnSelect').on('click', function(){
    SelectText("DivText");
 });


$('#BtnModalSelect').on('click', function(){
    SelectText("DivModalText"); 
  });

  function SelectText(elementId) {
    let elementHtml = document.getElementById(elementId);

    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(elementHtml);

    let selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any previous selection
    selection.addRange(range); // add range to selection object to select it        
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your intent once you've selected the text? Do you want to copy it?

Comment: @plumwd, yes, i have a separate method for that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

https://jsfiddle.net/plumwd/v0odtujb/47/

```
       $('#BtnSelect').on('click', function(){

        SelectText("DivText")
   });

    $('#BtnModalSelect').on('click', function(){

   SelectText("modalTxt");
  })

   function SelectText(elementId) {

        let elementHtml = document.getElementById(elementId);

        elementHtml.select();



    }
```

Create an input inside your div and then select the input. This works cross browser. You can style the input to have no border so it looks like regular text.

Comment: no in IE 11 It does not work.  But if you run the original code from the browser console (i.e.: SelectText("DivModalText"); ) it works!!!!!!

Comment: @plumwd, Still does not work in modal window in IE11. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Edited my comment above.